# Having trouble using Bootflat correctly.

Tags: jquery, css, node.js, twitter-bootstrap

I just found out a new and stylish bootstrap framework called [Bootflat](http://bootflat.github.io/index.html).

I have made a big mistake, which I started from their example page, I copied all the references tags and add it to my new html page and start writing my homepage code, after one day of coding and testing, I came across my navbar in small window, and it slides, but won't close back, than I searched about this problem, I finally fixed it, I have to reference to jquery.collapse.js, and it worked fine, but when I re-read there guide of installing there framework, I found out that I'm doing it wrong, they are saying that I have to install it using npm, and that's what I did. So, I wen't to nodejs.org and install it on my mac, I ran `npm install bootflat`, every things good, the problem here how to use it, because there are some scss files.

I would really like a simple step by step guide of how to use this framework correctly.

Comment: have you read the quick start that they have on there github page?

Comment: Yes, i did, the problem is, what i should put in my head tag ?? that i have now ?
css/site.min.css, /jquery.min.js, js/bootstrap.min.js, js/site.min.js  
the problem is why i installed there package in npm, and how to use there boot flat files ??

Comment: if u will only use the files then u only have to copy thats files to use. And the npm library is only if u have to modify the original files

Comment: Some late add: the [npm site](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootflat) provides an example of a minimal setup. (Nevertheless bootflat seems to be unmaintained since ~3 years now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The CSS can stand on its own." as stated in the [Getting Started](http://bootflat.github.io/getting-started.html#css-sass) you only *need* the npm library if you are planning on modifying how the library looks/acts.

Comment: Actually, the CSS doesn't appear to stand on it's own. It would be great if there was a real world example out there somewhere.

Comment: Actually, the CSS does stand on it's own unless the writer of the documentation is lying. "For simplicity you can always just add in your own CSS and override default properties."